# SQL - How to declare a variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below Oracle SQL syntax:

```
select effective_date
from table
 where effective_date >= to_date(:processingDate, 'yyyymmdd')
```

My error is

> 'processingDate' not declared .

Question: What does this mark ':' mean? Do I need to specify what is 'processingDate'? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello  Please edit the question and tag with the appropriate database platform and post a [mcve] that shows all the code definitions.  :processingDate is a bind variable, but without seeing the other code, can't really help  What is the client software written in?

Comment: Which dbms, what environment? (Parameter marker.)

Comment: Some systems use `:` preceding the name to denote a variable. Some use `?`. Others use `@`. To know what is right for your database, we need to know what kind of database you're using. `to_date()` narrows it down to Oracle or Postgresql, but that's still not enough, because I've also seen reporting tools that use `:` preceding the name for variables regardless of the ultimate database platform.

Comment: "SQL" - the standard query language has no variables. Some DBMS products extend the SQL standard and allow the use of variables in non-procedural code. So you need to tell us which DBMS product you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute query alone in sql*plus or in any of your tool then you can define this variable and use it using `substitution` variable. `:` is used for bind variables in oracle.

Substitution variable are declared using `&`.

So your case can go like this:

```
Define processingDate=20191023

select effective_date
from table
 where effective_date >= to_date('&processingDate', 'yyyymmdd');
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a variable (any of `varchar(8)`, `nvarchar(8)`, `char(8)`, or `nchar(8)`, since you match it to an 8-character fixed date format).

Some systems use `:` preceding the name to denote a variable name. Some use `?`. Others use `@`. Others don't require any leading character at all.

To know what is right for your database, we need to know what kind of database you're using. `to_date()` narrows it down to Oracle or Postgresql, but that's still not enough, because I've also seen reporting tools which use `:` preceding the name for variables regardless of the ultimate database platform.

But you probably don't want to just add a `DECLARE` statement for the variable. The variable alone is not helpful here unless it already has a meaningful value. You need to figure out where that value is supposed to come from, and make sure that system is set up to provide it correctly.

Comment: It's Oracle. I'm reading someone else's code, but I suppose 'processingDate' comes alone. Should I just declare this variable?

Comment: In Oracle, a colon prefix probably indicates a bind or host variable. Some desktop applications will prompt interactively, others need an explicit declaration. What desktop application are you using?